# Pretty Permalink Structure of wordpress not working on Godaddy host With windows hosting and IIS Server

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, permalinks

[image]

Above picture shows my problem, Go through many of the blogs, Godaddy support, stack overflow questions. FACING THIS PROBLEM FROM ONE MONTH, So at last Stack community to help.

There is no web.config file in my root folder but .htaccess file whom change does'nt effect permalinks.
**what should i do for creating this sort of permalink structure www.example.com/category/postname** as my current permalink structure is
http://www.example.com/?page_id=104
details of hosting server
Godaddy with windows hosting enviornment and iis 7 server.
Godaddy don'nt have any knowledge about this in there help center.

Comment: check out [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) and search for iis

Comment: @gwillie i've read this but did'nt found solution. iis 7 provide url rewrite and looks for web.config. So waiting for some one to provide exact web.config for mentioned permalink structure. Thanks

Comment: there's a link on the page i provided which goes to [iis website](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress). what @Uzair pasted is from that page

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to create a `web.config` file in the root directory of your WordPress installation (the same directory as the `.htaccess` file), and add the following code in `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This should enable pretty permalinks in WordPress with URL Rewrite running on IIS.

Comment: tumbs upp buddy, u've solved my problem straight away. Working Pretty Good n Excellent. Just copied paste n uploaded.
Thanks for Help

Comment: Thanks a lot as it was my first experience with windows server on URL Rewrite. so it really worked for me

Comment: This doesn't add query strings. How can I do it?